# Correctly committing versioned, and built (minified) files to GitHub with Gulp.js

Tags: git, github, workflow, gulp

**Background info**

I am writing a small JavaScript library and would like to make the contribution flow as easy as possible if others end up wanting to contribute. Currently, I am experiencing issues with versioning built files that go in the `dist` folder.

I am using:

- Git for version control, and Github for repository management.
- Gulp.js for building the source files and committing and pushing versioned files

Gulp runs a build task that concatenates, and minifies JavaScript files into a `all.min.js` file and places that file in a `dist` folder. The trouble I am having is making releases based on that folder.

**Things I've tried**

**1.**
Let the normal git flow occur even with built files. What I mean by this is that when a user creates a pull-request to master, one of the diffs would be the `all.min.js`. This often will cause conflicts, and when the pull-request is confirmed, the `all.min.js` is no longer tagged with "version1.x.x".

**2.**
My next idea was to add the `dist` folder to `.gitignore` and then use an npm package during the gulp build process to comment out the `dist` folder, commit and push, and then uncomment the line.

This of course does not work because as long as the `dist` folder exists in the repo, `.gitignore` will not work for that particular item.

**3.**
The last idea is when the developer is developing, to build those files to a `build` folder, and add that folder to `.gitignore`. This way, when I use Gulp to "release" I don't have a conflict of files, and tagging is consistent. The release tasks, and only those tasks would push to the `dist` folder. However, I still feel that this way is too open for mistakes. But, maybe this solution is the best.

**The Question:**
How can I improve any of these flows to get a consistent development cycle going?

Answer (score 0):

> … as long as the `dist` folder exists in the repo, `.gitignore` will not work for that particular item.

If you’ve already committed the `dist` and have committer’s remorse, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447) by running:

```
git rm --cached <file-or-directory>
```

I’d be interested in knowing what you ended up doing though.